# Counting occurrences of a value in data frame considering the order of the elements

Tags: r, counting

I'm new in R and I have this problem: I need to counting the occurrence of a value in a data frame, but considering the order.

Example:

This is my data frame with one column

```
Value     
(http_inspect) BARE BYTE UNICODE ENCODING
(http_inspect) BARE BYTE UNICODE ENCODING
(http_inspect) BARE BYTE UNICODE ENCODING
WEB-MISC Chunked-Encoding transfer attempt
WEB-MISC Chunked-Encoding transfer attempt
(http_inspect) BARE BYTE UNICODE ENCODING
(http_inspect) BARE BYTE UNICODE ENCODING
WEB-MISC Chunked-Encoding transfer attempt
WEB-MISC Chunked-Encoding transfer attempt
WEB-MISC Chunked-Encoding transfer attempt
```

So, i need to count and save it in a new data frame

```
Value                                          Frequency
(http_inspect) BARE BYTE UNICODE ENCODING          3
WEB-MISC Chunked-Encoding transfer attempt         2
(http_inspect) BARE BYTE UNICODE ENCODING          2
WEB-MISC Chunked-Encoding transfer attempt         3
```

So far i didn't find a method that solve my problem, so I coded this:

```
# data frame with one column 
dataset <- read.csv(path_file)

# new data frame to save name and frequency
df_weighted_graph <- data.frame(
name=character(),
frequency=numeric(),
stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)

# Variables
frequency <- 1
index <- 1

# Inicialize first position
df_weighted_graph[1,]$name <- dataset[1]
df_weighted_graph$[1,]frequency <- frequency

for(i in 1:length(dataset)-1)
{
   if(dataset[i] == dataset[i+1])
   {
      frequency <- frequency + 1
   }
   else{

     #Update frequency
     df_weighted_graph[index,]$frequency <- frequency

     index <- index + 1
     frequency <- 1

     # New element
     df_weighted_graph[index,]$name <- dataset[i]
     df_weighted_graph[index,]$frequency <- frequency
   }
}
```

It shows some error message in:

> Error in if (dataset[i] == dataset[i + 1]) { : argument is of length zero

and i'm not able to pass this as string

> df_weighted_graph[1,]$name <- dataset[1]

It saves as a number and not as the name in the dataset.

Any help with the code or a better idea is thankful!

## Edit

For the second output error

> df_weighted_graph[1,]$name <- dataset[1]

It's because a missed the argue stringsAsFactors=False in read.csv command.

So, to solve this should be

read.csv(path_file, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

Comment: Did you manage and try the table function?

Answer (score 0):

Use the table function.

```
table(data$value)
```

Comment: Sorry for my late reply.. in that case table wouldn't work. With table it would put together tuplas with the same value losting the order so. But thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide a minimal reproducible example, but using the bit of data your show in the question, here is a simple approach that seems to give what you want.

```
values = c(
    "(http_inspect) BARE BYTE UNICODE ENCODING",
    "(http_inspect) BARE BYTE UNICODE ENCODING",
    "(http_inspect) BARE BYTE UNICODE ENCODING",
    "WEB-MISC Chunked-Encoding transfer attempt",
    "WEB-MISC Chunked-Encoding transfer attempt",
    "(http_inspect) BARE BYTE UNICODE ENCODING",
    "(http_inspect) BARE BYTE UNICODE ENCODING",
    "WEB-MISC Chunked-Encoding transfer attempt",
    "WEB-MISC Chunked-Encoding transfer attempt",
    "WEB-MISC Chunked-Encoding transfer attempt"
)

# table just counts up all instances of the unique values (you say this is NOT what you want)
table(values)

# To get runs of adjacent values, use 'run length encoding'
rle(values)

# If you want this as a data.frame output (as your question suggests), you can bind the 'lengths' and 'values' together
as.data.frame(do.call("cbind", rle(values)))
```

This gives a table with the number of adjacent occurrences of each value:

```
  lengths                                     values
1       3  (http_inspect) BARE BYTE UNICODE ENCODING
2       2 WEB-MISC Chunked-Encoding transfer attempt
3       2  (http_inspect) BARE BYTE UNICODE ENCODING
4       3 WEB-MISC Chunked-Encoding transfer attempt
```